# Get button to appear beside item in the KendoComboBox on hover

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I'm trying to have a button display to the right of the item in the KendoComboBox list that is currently being hovered on. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

(The end goal is that if this button is clicked, the corresponding item text should become an editable field.)

I started from the following [demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/template.html) and I've been looking through the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox) but I can't seem to find any mention of having a popup button appear beside an item in the list (almost like a side popup menu with the only one item, the button, for each item in the KendoComboBox).

I've included my current prototyping code below. I can make the "licenseHoverButton" appear within the list item but I'm not sure how to make it appear beside.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="example" class="k-content">

        <div class="demo-section">
            <h2>Licenses</h2>
            <input id="licenses" style="width: 400px;"/>
        </div>

        <script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
            <div class="licenseListItem">
                # if (data.expired) { #
                    <p class="licenseName">#=data.name# (Expired)</p>
                    <button class="licenseHoverButton">Remove</button>
                #} else { #
                    <p class="licenseName">#=data.name#</p>
                    <button class="licenseHoverButton">Rename</button>
                #} #
                <p class="licenseUsage">#=data.remaining#/#=data.total#GB</p>

            </div>
        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var mydata = [{ "name":"License Name", "remaining":"24", "total":"60", "expired":false},
                                { "name":"1234-1234-1234-1234", "remaining":"60", "total":"60", "expired":false},
                                { "name":"Old License Name", "remaining":"2", "total":"60", "expired":true}];
                $("#licenses").kendoComboBox({
                    dataTextField: "name",
                    dataValueField: "name",
                    filter:"startswith",
                    template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                    dataSource: mydata
                });

                var combobox = $("#licenses").data("kendoComboBox");
            });

        </script>

        <style scoped>                
            .demo-section {
                width: 400px;
                padding: 30px;
            }
            .demo-section h2 {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            #licenses-list .k-item {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #licenses-list .k-item .licenseHoverButton{
                display: none;
            }
            #licenses-list .k-item.k-state-hover .licenseHoverButton {
                display: block;
            }
            #licenses-list .k-item.k-state-hover .licenseUsage {
                display: none;
            }
            #licenses-list p {
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using tooltip ? http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/BfyPf/1/
(The "remove" button to have it in-line with the item, but that is not what you after I am guessing ?)

```
 <script id="btnTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                 <button class="licenseHoverButton">Rename</button>
    </script>

  var tooltip = $('.licenseName').kendoTooltip({
      position: "right",
       content: kendo.template($("#btnTemplate").html())
  }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, clicking the button closes the combo box. Is it possible to keep the drop down open so that I can make the item text editable? (I'm referring to the end goal I mentioned in my initial question)

Comment: The tool tip isn't a useful result as I can't add an on click handler to the button that is in the tool tip. Try adding the following lines to your fiddle and see what I mean.$('.licenseHoverButton').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
});